# Is it possible to launch the android app widgets screen or list?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

Can an intent be constructed to launch the app widgets screen or list where the user can choose an app widget to add to the home screen?

Comment: See related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829647/programmatically-add-the-widget-to-home-screen-in-android

Answer (score 3):

I just opened `Add Widget` while watching LogCat and I saw this, maybe it will help:

`Starting: Intent {act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_PICK}`

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Following your hint, I took a look at the code of launcher (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher), and used the following code to launch the list:
                          Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK); 
                    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 1024);
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 9);

Comment: However, clicking a widget does not do anything.

Comment: @Hong Is it possible to add a widget from that chooser dialog?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I do not know how.

Comment: Did you figure out how to open the widget list and then allow the user to add it to home screen?

Comment: @RowanGontier No, unfortunately.