# Android share text/plain to be able to use in the widget

Tags: java, android, android-intent, shared, url-scheme

[image]

I need to share a text/plain, between an external app and my app and use this shared text as url for the widget I need to insert, see example image.

So every widget must have instance which depends on this text.

How can I make sure that when the share is clicked and then on the specific app, the widget is automatically inserted on the home screen.

Can you give me a hand?

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyWidget"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".WidgetService"
            android:enabled="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

AlarmHandler:

```java
package com.myapp.test;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AlarmHandler {

    private final Context context;

    public AlarmHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setAlarmManager() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        int FlagPendingIntent = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : 0;
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent, FlagPendingIntent);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //get current time and add 1 hour
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long l = c.getTimeInMillis() + 10000;//1000*60*60=3600000

        //set the alarm for 10 seconds in the future
        if (am != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                am.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, sender);
            } else {
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, sender);
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancelAlarmManager() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        int FlagPendingIntent = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : 0;
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent, FlagPendingIntent);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (am != null) {
            am.cancel(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

WakeLocker:

```java
package com.myapp.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;

public abstract class WakeLocker {

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    //wake the device
    public static void acquire(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock != null) {
            wakeLock.release();
        }

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WIDGET: Wake lock acquired!");
        wakeLock.acquire(2000);
    }

    public static void release() {
        if (wakeLock != null) {
            wakeLock.release();
        }
        wakeLock = null;
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```java
package com.myapp.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                String url = extractLinks(sharedText);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager = getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);

                    ComponentName myProvider = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, MyWidget.class);

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("url", url);
                    if (mAppWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
                        Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyWidget.class);
                        PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                                pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

                        mAppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, b, successCallback);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String extractLinks(String text) {
        List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            String url = m.group();
            links.add(url);
        }

        return links.toArray(new String[links.size()])[0].split("/")[4];
    }
}
```

WidgetService:

```java
package com.myapp.test;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class WidgetService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String values = "Test";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //wake the device
        WakeLocker.acquire(context);

        //increase the number in the widget
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        //int value = preferences.getInt("value", 1);

        //String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        //Log.d("WidgetService", url.toString());
        Log.d("WidgetService", values);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("value", values);
        editor.apply();

        //force widget update
        Intent widgetIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
        widgetIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class));
        widgetIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        context.sendBroadcast(widgetIntent);

        Log.d("WIDGET", "Widget set to update!");

        //go back to sleep
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
}
```

MyWidget:

```java
package com.myapp.test;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    String values = "MyWidget";

    void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_design);

        Log.d("MyWidget3", values);

        //set the value in the textview
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, values);

        //update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        //reschedule the widget refresh
        AlarmHandler alarmHandler = new AlarmHandler(context);
        alarmHandler.cancelAlarmManager();
        alarmHandler.setAlarmManager();

        Log.d("WIDGET", "Widget updated!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId: appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        //stop updating the widget
        AlarmHandler alarmHandler = new AlarmHandler(context);
        alarmHandler.cancelAlarmManager();

        Log.d("WIDGET", "Widget removed!");
    }
}
```

Edits:

I've added all the classes I'm using that come into play, I've managed to get the widget to be added when text is shared.

But I was unable to retrieve the text on the widget side.

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

you can't place app widget on home screen programmatically in any way, user must take some system action to place it, e.g. pick from app launcher menu and drag to home

but starting Android 8 / API 26 there is a new method [`requestPinAppWidget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) - so pass your data/link do dedicated `Activity` and use linked method to force system to show add-app-widget-dialog. some example, including passing data in `Bundle`, in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829647/programmatically-add-the-widget-to-home-screen-in-android)

Comment: I've added all the classes I'm using that come into play, I've managed to get the widget to be added when text is shared.

But I was unable to retrieve the text on the widget side.

Can you tell me if it should be better to do it on WidgetService or on MyWidget?

I tried both but failed.